# Pairing a bluetooth device with iOS using Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, bluetooth

I'm connecting to a BLE device in a Cordova application using the [ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central) plugin. I can connect to the device from the application without a problem, when I connect to the device from iOS I get prompted for the PIN and on entering the PIN I get connected, all as expected.

The problem is that the device does not get remembered on iOS, and that every time the application is restarted, or if the connection fails, I get prompted for the PIN again.

Is there a way to force iOS to remember the device? The strange thing is that even though I can connect to the device from the application, or something like the [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) application I cannot seem to detect the device from the settings.

Not sure if this is some iOS limitation, if the device should somehow be iOS enabled like older devices did? It seems to me I wouldn't be able to connect at all if that was the case?

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Comment: show the code you have tried so far and which device your are testing with?

Comment: also pairing should be done via Settings->Bluetooth .once you pair it it remembers it

Comment: I'm aware of that, but like I said, I don't 'see' the device through the settings, but can connect to it from code. There is no special code, I'm using the connect method, and it works, as per plugin documentation here:

https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#connect

The only problem is that I cannot 'save' the device.

Comment: Oh forgot the device, I tested on iPhone 6 and an iPod, it was tested on an older iPhone as well, but I don't have it here.